# automate the walk of a ppt like series of web pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

This would count under javascript injection, but i figured to ask anyways, just in case people know an answer.

I have a web page that counts down to zero before letting you go to the next page.  I have a script that will check to see when it is 0 and then will click the anchor tag.  The issue is that this opens a new page so the javascript does not persist across pages.  I was trying to figure out a way to make it so though.   Not sure if i could just execute it inside of an iframe and then work my way into that iframe or not.  I am sure that would be the option to go if anything.

My real goal is just to inject something like the following at the runtime so it will auto walk the web-ppt they have created.

```
setInterval(function () {
    if (!$("li.next").is(".disabled")) {
        $("li.next > a.timer")[0].click();
    }
}, 1000);
```

**Edit**
I am trying to use Tampermonkey as a plugin to add this script.  Right now, i have the following script.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Hunt Ed Script
// @namespace    http://your.homepage/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Used to Auto Progress the Web PPT
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.hunter-ed.com/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==

$(function(){
  setInterval(function () {
    if (!$("li.next").is(".disabled")) {
        $("li.next > a.timer")[0].click();
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

but when i load the page, it says "no scripts are running".

Here is what a URL looks like for their site:  `https://www.hunter-ed.com/pennsylvania/course_content/course/201039/section/700092000?token=fe0a130033c7440e636534ee98029341`

Comment: if its on the same domain you can store values across pages with localStorage

Comment: im trying to do this auto walker externally js console.  So while i could add that to localStorage, i would have no way to store and execute that functoin on load really, unless i am mistaken.

Comment: if you are looking to inject code into a website which you can´t modify, you should try greasemonekey or tampermonkey approaches

Comment: I am trying to use tampermonkey (since im on chrome), can you help walk me through it?  It seems my script doesnt seem to be working.  Ill make an edit to my post and show you what the script says

Comment: Guess you are missing the ' www. ' part on the match attribute. Beware that unless the page already includes jquery, you will need to add it yourself. Also be sure that the script is enabled

Comment: true, i saw that tag, but it does have it already

Comment: Alright that is a great answer.  I will accept it if you want to place it.  If not ill answer it.  The script works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injection to another websites which you can not modify are usually done with browser addons or extensions. However, as this is usually harder to do for simple scripts, both greasemonkey and tampermonkey allow a quick setup of running a script on the pages you want. In your case, this would suffice.

You can use any library in your script that has been included in the website, but you have to manually add the ones that are not. Both chrome/firefox extensions have a lot of documentation on this